# Lower case Action Buttons in Android (default/not-custom) Notification

Tags: android, button, notifications, lowercase

Is there a way to make the buttons on an Android notification lowercase (instead of all capitals), without building a custom notification 'from scratch'?

In this example, the "REPLY" and "ARCHIVE", would become "Reply" and "Archive":
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TW17I.png

**Edit**

So I don't really know what I am doing here. But one thing that I tried, was to modify various style templates (50+, basically every single one I thought might be involved), to look like this

```
  <style name="TextAppearance.Compat.Notification" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent">
  <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
  </style>
```

This did not work. However, because I do not know what I am doing exactly, I may have made a mistake. Any advice on this approach is also appreciated.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Lower case is now supported from Android 11, just provide the text in the desired form to NotificationCompat.Action() and the rest will be done by android.